# Intellij - disable tab for new lines

Tags: intellij-idea

I use Intellij in Mac. I am new to mac.

I would like to write my java code like this.

```
list
  .stream()
  .map(String::upperCase())
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But Intellij in Mac adds new tabs for everyline. Unable to remove. I  did not have this issue in my window OS.

```
list
  .stream()
      .map(String::upperCase())
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

How to correct this!!

Comment: Check [this](https://i.imgur.com/dml5Os7.png) option (Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Chained method calls | Align when multiline)

Comment: awesome man!! Please add as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Chained method calls | Align when multiline**:

[image]